# PHP run code from txt file

Tags: php, text-files

If i had a text file on my web server, which contains full PHP code, all properly formatted, could i use PHP fopen to read the text file and echo the output of the PHP to the browser. Ie. Run PHP code that is held in a text file rather than hard coded?

Thanks

Comment: why would you want to do this? I don't think you can.

Comment: @Mark Baker that won't execute the code, it'll just include it as plain text

Comment: I want to send PHP code from an iphone app to a text file on my web host and have a script read and echo the result back down to the iPhone app

Comment: Why? Would Apple even allow that?

Comment: if it contains a regular php opening tag, the file will be executed when including it. If not, you can still use eval()... But don't forget: eval() is evil!

Comment: Why would apple not allow that, its so web devs can test code on their iPhone (simulating a real web server)

Comment: @jakenoble - Difficult to determine from the OP whether <?php is present in the file or not... I'd assume that to be a requirement for "full PHP code"

Comment: Yeah it would start with <?php and end with ?>

Comment: I think Apple would allow it since you do not execute the foreign code on their device... but in general... wth are you trying to achieve? There has to be a better solution!

Comment: care to take a guess at a better solution :)

Comment: Whoever voted the question down, can you explain your action please?

Comment: @benhowdle89 You *might* want to open a new "How can I do this?" question that specifically defines the problem you're trying to solve regarding getting data from the iPhone to the web server (and presumably then doing something with that data). The more background details you provide (what's the data for, how will it be used, etc.) the better.

Comment: +1 This is a strange question, but it might be usefull to know the answer. Knowing more about how php handles includes is NEVER a bad thing. Sometimes you have to modify or extend an existing applicatioon and telling your boss that you will not do the job because the original approach is bad is NOT a good idea! And running into "DO NOT DO THIS" and "why do you need this?" answers all over SO is just anoying. Just include your warnings in a VALID answer, so people know the risks the take when they use your sollution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's perfectly possible to do this (it's just another file after all), although I'd be tempted to directly include it rather that messing around with fopen/eval, etc. (N.B.: The file would of course have to be "fully formed" and begin with "`<?php`", etc. for the include to work.)

However, I'd be **very** wary of naming the file with a .txt extension as this will mean that it'll be possible to browse the contents of this file directly from the browser if it exists in the public HTTP docs area. As such, why not simply write the data into a .php file - this will be no more difficult than a .txt file and offers the advantage that it always be parsed by the web server if someone attempts to access it.

Comment: I didnt realise i could do that :) so i could get the user to write out their php and then i could send a whole PHP file to my web server?

Comment: @benhowdle89 - The app will let people write PHP? (If so, that's a **massive** security risk on an almost incalculable level.) Irrespective, there's nothing inherently clever going on here, although you'll obviously need a script to pick up the files and store them in a sane location, etc.

Comment: Can you explain why this is a risk? Better know now :)

Comment: @benhowdle89 If you're allowing people to enter their own PHP code and execute it on your server, then it could obviously do anything that a native script could, as there's no realistic means of creating a "sandbox" environment to run such things in. I'd be tempted to update your new question with what you're specifically planning on doing.

Answer (score 2):

You can read in the file as you suggested using [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) you can then execute the string that is read in using [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). I wouldn't recommend this. Try another solution to what ever the actual problem is.