# PHP file execution txt doc

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP run code from txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722261/php-run-code-from-txt-file)

Php... is it possible to execute a txt in a server that contains a php script?
I need to execute this somehow 
The file is in txt extension.. Please tell me if
It's possible

Answer (score 1):

Just use **include**, but be aware that this is very insecure.

This is of course assuming the .txt file also includes the PHP open tags. If not, you could read the file to a string and use eval to execute the code...

Answer (score 0):

The ending txt is for text files.  If you are saying that you wish to display the content of a text file, then you have to create a php program that will do it.
You might want to look at file_get_contents in php.